# Sql sort by query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an Sql query that is the union of three queries, for example :

```
 query1 
 Union 
 query2 
 Union 
 query3
```

I want to ask if there is a way to have the output respective by queries , such that the results of query1 are first in the ResultSet , query2 second and query3 at then end.

Thank you

Comment: add sample data and expected output

Answer (score 4):

You would normally do this by including a column specifying the query and ordering by that:

```
select . . .
from ((select q.*, 1 as ordering from (<query1>) q) union all
      (select q.*, 2 as ordering from (<query2>) q) union all
      (select q.*, 3 as ordering from (<query3>) q)
     ) q
order by ordering;
```

Note:  This replaces the `union` with `union all`, so duplicates are not removed.

Comment: every query is from a different table and has different joins , how can i apply this to my query?

Comment: @AbdallaIsmail . . . Put your queries where `<query?>` is.  Or, use CTEs so the code is easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for help , however in the results there is an addition column named ordering, how can i remove it?

Comment: @AbdallaIsmail in the first line you list the columns you want instead of writing `*`

Comment: @GordonLinoff I made 3 CTES instead of the 3 queries , however i am using {select COALESCE(Type,'Total found transfers'),total,totalSum from grpSum} instead of q.*. In the results I got Total found transfers Row in the middle of the result set not at the end.How can i solve this?